# How to download/Export data from Apache Solr to CSV file? i have created collection in Solr and i would like to export the data from Solr to CSV

Tags: solr

Iam new to Solr and installed  Solr 7.5.0 on my local and created a collection with sample json file,iam able to query it and view the data.my requirement is to download the same data as CSV into my local.Please help me out.
[image]

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Use `Solr` select endpoint to extract all documents with `q=*:*` and `csv` as the responseWriter.

you r query will look like :

```
http:/localhost:8886/solr/product/select?q=*:*&wt=csv&indent=true
```

Another alternative is to use `/export` to make requests to export the result set of a query.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have done this step, post that still iam unable to find download option. Posted the screen shot in the original question. Please let me know if iam doing some thing wrong.

Comment: when someone will click on the download then you have invoke the url create csv file by adding the sole response to it. Then that file should be sent in the response...Nothing will happen automatically

Comment: Hi Abhijit, sorry for asking the basic questions as iam completely new to Solr,can you please explain me the process in detail.

Comment: I hope this will help you...https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-export-data-to-csv-file-java/